# Not allowed to load local resource: file:// using iframe in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iframe

i am working in MVC and i am trying to preview a pdf from web-server but it is showing error as :

Not allowed to load local resource: file://web-server/images/1324/Sample%20Document.pdf

```
<iframe src="@Model.urlpath" width="650" height="350" style="border: 1px solid #ccc; margin:10px 5px !important;"></iframe>
```

i am trying to get this url path from web server to local application

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML embedded PDF iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654577/html-embedded-pdf-iframe)

Comment: What URL string contained inside `@Model.urlpath`? If URL string is known, the problem should be easily solved.

Answer (score 0):

Default security setting for modern browsers disallows usage of `file://` protocol in elements with `src` attribute, including `iframe` (related issues [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37690419/not-allowed-to-load-local-resources) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38159480/not-allowed-to-load-local-resource), see also **[same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)**). Use server's relative path instead as in example below.

**Controller**

```
var model = new ViewModel();
model.urlpath = string.Format("~/images/{0}/{1}", "1324", "Sample_Document.pdf");
```

**View**

```html
<iframe src="@Url.Content(Model.urlpath)" width="650" height="350" style="border: 1px solid #ccc; margin:10px 5px !important;"></iframe>
```

Or use hardcoded virtual path inside `@Url.Content` and just pass file name from viewmodel property:

**Controller**

```
var model = new ViewModel();
model.FileName = "Sample_Document.pdf";
```

**View**

```html
<iframe src="@Url.Content("~/images/1324" + Model.FileName)" width="650" height="350" style="border: 1px solid #ccc; margin:10px 5px !important;"></iframe>
```